# MeteorJS: Can not assign a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, callback

I have such code, and want to assign one variable to another in function, code example:

```
Meteor.methods({
              parsing:function(){
                var aa ;
                request("https://google.com/", function(error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                          var k=1;
                          aa = k;
                    }
                });
                console.log(aa);
              }
});
```

It's loged `undefined`, can someone explain me why ?

**EDIT :**

```
 Meteor.methods({
                  parsing:function(){
                    var aa ;
                    var tmp;
                    request("https://google.com/", function(error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                              var k=1;
                              aa = k;
                              console.log(aa);
                              request("https://google.com/xyz", function(error, response, body) {
                                tmp = response.request.uri.href;
                              });
                        }
                        console.log(tmp);
                    });

                  }
    });
```

For example i need `console.log(tmp);` only when my second request will be call (ended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that you give as parameter of `request` will only be executed when the request will have an answer from Google. But the next part of the code (your `console.log` line) is still executed without waiting anything.

If you want to wait the request result before your log, add it to your function:

```
parsing:function(){
    var aa ;
    request("https://google.com/", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              var k=1;
              aa = k;
              console.log(aa);
        }
    });
}
```

### EDIT :

Well, you can use the same technique as many times you want:

```
parsing:function(){
    var aa ;
    var tmp;
    request("https://google.com/", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var k=1;
            aa = k;
            console.log(aa); // Waited the first answer.
            request("https://google.com/xyz", function(error, response, body) {
                tmp = response.request.uri.href;
                console.log(tmp); // Waited the second one.
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Good but if i want to add new request in if body, how i can wait while second callback dont call

Comment: @nlpkr Please edit your question if you want to put more code, it's not readable in comment format.

Comment: Yep, did this in post

Comment: @nlpkr Answer done. You can use the same method any times you want.

Comment: but if i need to do `console.log()` not in callback ?

Comment: @nlpkr The part of your code outside your callbacks will be executed before request answers. So you cannot try to read variables that you set inside callbacks, or you won't get something else than `undefined`.

Comment: And i have only one way is to put all my logic in second callback if i want that my code must work only when `tmp = response.request.uri.href;` assigned, it's right ?

Comment: If you want to wait your callback, you have to put your code inside it, yes,

Comment: Now I finally understood callbacks, i love you